# Use threading to wait for another class's method to execute, or is there a simpler way?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, facebook, cocoa-touch, ios4

I've never touched threads before, and by the looks of it I might have to delve into them a little, but I was wondering if there was a simpler solution to the problem below.

I'm basically displaying a list of a user's Facebook friends in a `UITableView`. I have a `FacebookWrapper` class that contains all my Facebook methods, and a `FacebookViewController` that has a variety of buttons/options. Finally, there is a `FriendsViewController` that displays the list of Friends. The user can choose to display a list of male friends, or female friends by pressing the relevant button in the `FacebookViewController`.

If they hit male friends for example, I use FBL to create a query string which I add to a dictionary and use to return a list of male friends (all in the wrapper).

```
[facebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query" andParams:dictionary andHttpMethod:@"GET" andDelegate:self];
```

The delegate methods in the wrapper class handle the `FBRequest` that is returned. I have the following methods to determine what's happening when:

```
- (void)requestLoading:(FBRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Loading...");
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Response received");
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Request failed");
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoadRawResponse:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"Request did load raw response");
}
```

However, when I hit the 'male friends' button for example, I want to wait until the response has been generated before pushing the `FriendsViewController` and displaying the list. As it stands now, the FriendsVC is pushed before the request has returned the list, and so I get a blank list. I have to wait for "Request did load raw response" before refreshing the table and displaying the results. Currently the method to call and display the friends list in the `FacebookViewController` looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)friendsButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    int selectionTag = [sender tag];

    //Get access to the instance of the wrapper in the app delegate (since it needs to remain refereced after app exits to log in and returns
    MiniBfAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MiniBfAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.facebookWrapper loadListDataFor:selectionTag];

    //Initialise the friends view controller
    FriendsViewController *friendsViewController = [[FriendsViewController alloc] init];

    //NEED TO WAIT UNTIL LISTDATA IS RETURNED?

    //Give the friends view controller the list data
    friendsViewController.listData = appDelegate.facebookWrapper.friendsList;

    //Push the friends view controller
    friendsViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:friendsViewController animated:YES];
    [friendsViewController release];
}
```

So ideally, I'd like to display a loading symbol while I wait for the wrapper to return the list, and once it does, push the FriendsViewController so it is populated immediately. So do I need to use threads or is there a simpler way?

Perhaps this is answering my own question, and it might be that I'm failing to grasp a fundamental concept here, but aside from creating an instance of the FriendsVC in my App Delegate, is there a way I can send the current instance a message from the Wrapper class? So I could just tell it to `refresh` in the wrapper's `request: didLoadRawResponse:` method, i.e. when the list is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you may want to look into the NSNotificationCenter. You can use it to send messages to your controllers, here's an example of triggering a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotificationName" 
                                                        object:self 
                                                      userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:XXXX forKey:@"someObject"]];
```

As you can see, you can even send parameters to it. And in the target controller you just register an observer to respond to those messages:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(yourMethodHere:) 
                                                 name: @"myNotificationName"
                                               object: nil];
```

Regards!

Comment: Well that almost worked. It now waits until the notification before loading the FriendsVC, but it still loads blank first time... until I go back and push the button a second time. I also get these errors in the output: nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar, Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted, AND Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <FriendsViewController: 0xce6c990>. As it sort of describes, the navigation bar seems to have duplicated. Is this to do with the notifications?

Comment: Actually I seem to have removed those errors by removing the observer when the FriendsVC loads ([[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"ListReady" object:nil];) It still doesn't load the list first time though... will continue to investigate but it's looking good thanks.

Comment: Oh I found the problem - I was sending the notification from the request didReceiveResponse method rather than the request: request didLoad: method. Now it all works great - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's simple. Put your VC loading code into didReceiveResponce method. And show UIAlertView in didFailWithError.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Response received");

    //Give the friends view controller the list data
    friendsViewController.listData = appDelegate.facebookWrapper.friendsList;

    //Push the friends view controller
    friendsViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:friendsViewController animated:YES];
    [friendsViewController release];
}
```

Comment: Except that the wrapper class containing the didReceiveResponse method has no navigationController on to which to push the FriendsVC...?

Comment: Or is there a way to access the current navigation controller from an instance of the wrapper class?

Comment: It's your wrapper class. So you could just add property for navigation controller in this class. and fill it, when you create your wrapper class inside FriendsVC.

Comment: Or even more flexible. You could set onSuccess and onFail blocks for your Wrapper. and fill those blocks from FriendsVC so navigation controller will be available and code will look clean and simple.

Comment: That's great advice thanks - but could you explain your last comment a little more - what do you mean by fill the blocks from FriendsVC?

Comment: something like
`wrapper.successBlock = ^{
    friendsViewController.listData = appDelegate.facebookWrapper.friendsList;
    friendsViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:friendsViewController animated:YES];
    [friendsViewController release];
};`

and then in wrapper you just run it. `successBlock();`
You should read about Blocks in obj-c for more details. They are really powerful.

Comment: Great - thanks. I don't know much about blocks so I'll check them out. Cheers!